# How can I get MIME type of the http response with media subtype?

Tags: go, get, mime-types

I want to store MIME type of the response obtained from GET request. I have used the `DetectContentType` function but it gives me `text/plain; charset=utf-8` for both js and css resource. I have to distinguish the filetype for each url and I'm depending on MIME type for that purpose.

```
response, error := http.Get(url) 
if error == nil { 
    contentType := response.Header.Get("Content-Type") 
    // ... 
}
```

Only gives me content type.

Comment: Your Go program is making requests to a server and you are trying to get the MIME type of the response? Have you checked if the content type is set correctly by the server?

Comment: I'm trying to crawl sites. Is it a bad idea for crawler? Because we cannot be certain about it.

Comment: @Sunil it's probably a badly configured server. In HTML files you can also check META tags for overriding headers or lacking headers. In JS and CSS you might want to add heuristic checks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you could use Go's mime package. The TypeByExtension method in the mime package might suit your needs. https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#TypeByExtension

I believe this uses the host system's mime type table. It is possible that the mime type determined by this method could be different than the mime type reported by the remote server.

```
import "mime"

func DetermineMimeType (fileExtension string) string {
    return mime.TypeByExtension(fileExtension)
}
```

Be sure to pass in the full file extension including the period, for example ".js" or ".css". Just to cover all the cases, if you can't determine the file's extension or this method doesn't return a mime type then perhaps default to the mime type reported by the remote server.

Comment: Would any down voters explain what you disagree with?

Comment: Because the OP wanted to get the content type of the file, your solution only checks for an extension, which is unrealiable and not useful at all for what the OP wanted. (Disclosure: I did not downvote because the solution was already written in comments of the post)

Comment: @rsz Fair enough. Looking at it again, I should have read it more carefully. I thought it was a question of how to determine MIME types in general where what OP wanted was to get the MIME type from the response header.
Though I disagree about file extensions. They are how system typically determine what kind of file it is. Also, web servers use file extensions to determine the MIME type returned in the response header.